# Highcharts - use navigator as a seperate time selector

Tags: highcharts, slider

I have more than one chart in one page, all of them uses same data but in different chart types.

I would like to change all of their time with only one navigator on the top. like using it as a datepicker input, how can i achieve that?

Comment: Show us your code thus we can understand your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `afterSetExtremes` event callback function and apply the same extremes on the rest charts:

```
    xAxis: {
        events: {
            afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
                var min = e.userMin,
                    max = e.userMax;

                chart1.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max, true, false);
                chart2.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max, true, false);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8gc9qwsp/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes